# Is there any way to get the BitLocker password from the laptop?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, data-recovery, bitlocker, windows-8

I have a personal hard disk of 1TB with lot of data.
I connected it to my office laptop and the drive got bitlocked automatically within a second.

I talk to the office administrators and we ran the command thru administrators right.

```
manage-bde -protectors e: -get
```

But it is printing only the ID and not the password.

Is there any way I can get the password?

I did not try to lock it explicitly.

It was done by system automatically and is there any way I can find the recovery key or password from that system?

This issue has been raised by other people in the past as well.

[image]
Please help.

Comment: *"get bitlocked automatically within a second."* - Are you sure? I don't think its possible for a lot of data to be read, encrypted and written back within one second.

Comment: @nobody I am sure. I almost got a heart attack. This issue has been faced by other people as well. See the image i added in question. But i haven't been able to find the solution. Can #Microsoft help in this case?

Comment: @Thinker There might not be a password: the encryption key can just be on the computer's TPM chipset. From the computer where you can access the decrypted content of your drive, disable bitlocker. The command you quoted just did what it it supposed to do, and that's not disabling bitlocker.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way I can get the password?

Probably not, most likely because there almost certainly isn't any password. Bitlocker doesn't require one, and it doesn't even make sense to create one without asking the user. However, if `manage-bde` says there's a password, that suggests there is. It won't be stored in a recoverable form anywhere, though.

You *can* get the recovery key, if there is one, via the `manage-bde` command you mentioned; if present, it's under "Numerical password" (see https://www.top-password.com/blog/tag/get-bitlocker-recovery-key-from-cmd/). While the recovery key is by default mandatory when using Bitlocker from the UI, it's not actually required for Bitlocker in general; a drive might not have one. You can create one (and save it somewhere) using `manage-bde -protectors -add e: -RecoveryPassword` or similar.

You can try `manage-bde -changepassword e:` and see if it will let you set a (new?) password. If the drive is already unlocked - as I assume it must be - you might not need the existing password.

You should be able to "suspend" Bitlocker (make it so that the data is technically encrypted but the key is stored in plain text and therefore any Bitlocker-aware machine can access the drive automatically) by using `manage-bde -protectors -disable e:`. Alternatively, you can just decrypt the drive altogether using `manage-bde -off e:`. This might be blocked by the same policy (probably pushed by your domain controller) that mandated encryption in the first place.

---

As a side note, don't plug in personal devices to corporate machines. Depending on your employment contract, you might not even be allowed to take the data on that "personal" hard disk out of your company again - which could be enforced by encrypting it with a key the domain controller has but you don't - and your only *official* way to get the drive back is to reformat it (which will remove Bitlocker). It's also a risk for the corporate machines.

Answer (score 0):

The password will only be displayed when the partition is unlocked. The fact that there is a password should be known to you administrator and he should be able to retrieve it after he could see what the ID is.